# Why does read_csv skiprows value need to be lower than it should be in this case?

Tags: python, python-3.x, pandas, dataframe, csv

I have a log file (Text.TXT in this case):

```
# 1: 5
# 3: x
# F: 5.
# ID: 001
# No.: 2
# No.: 4
# Time: 20191216T122109
# Value: ";"
# Time: 4
# Time: ""
# Time ms: ""
# Date: ""
# Time separator: "T"
# J: 1000000
# Silent: false
# mode: true
Timestamp;T;ID;P
16T122109957;0;6;0006
```

To read in this log file into pandas and ignore all the header info I would use `skiprows` up to line 16 like so:

```
pd.read_csv('test.TXT',skiprows=16,sep=';')
```

But this produces `EmptyDataError` as it is skipping past where the data is starting. To make this work I've had to use it on line 11:

```
pd.read_csv('test.TXT',skiprows=11,sep=';')
      Timestamp  T  ID  P
0  16T122109957  0   6  6
```

My question is if the data doesn't start until row 17, in this case, why do I need to request a skiprows up to row 11?

Comment: When I did `pd.read_csv(StringIO(text),header=15,sep=';')` it gave me an error `ParserError: Passed header=15 but only 13 lines in file`. I think this is a bug. Atleast this explains why it worked fine with 11.

Comment: @Ch3steR I believe it is a bug when the 'sep' parameter is passed. `pd.read_csv(StringIO(text),skiprows=16)`  seems to work fine (in terms of skipping the correct amount of rows).

Comment: Yes, without `sep` it worked fine. This seems like a bug. You can open an issue in GitHub if one regarding this doesn't exist.

Comment: @Ch3steR replacing the ; instances within the header with commas seems to make it skip the correct number of rows.

Comment: @Ch3steR I will look at submitting an issue

Answer (score 3, accepted):

One work around is to use `comment` parameter of [`pd.read_csv`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.read_csv.html)

```
from io import StringIO

text='''# 1: 5
# 3: x
# F: 5.
# ID: 001
# No.: 2
# No.: 4
# Time: 20191216T122109
# Value: ";"
# Time: 4
# Time: ""
# Time ms: ""
# Date: ""
# Time separator: "T"
# J: 1000000
# Silent: false
# mode: true
Timestamp;T;ID;P
16T122109957;0;6;0006'''

df = pd.read_csv(StringIO(text),comment='#',sep=';')
df
      Timestamp  T  ID  P
0  16T122109957  0   6  6
```

Or

```
df = pd.read_csv(StringIO(text),header=0,comment='#',sep=';')
```

From docs under header parameter:

> Note that this parameter ignores commented lines and empty lines if skip_blank_lines=True, so header=0 denotes the first line of data rather than the first line of the file.

Not sure about `skiprows`'s weird behaviour here.